# Grails remoting plugin RMI MissingMethodException

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I would like to use grails remoting plugin to connect to remote RMI service.
So I have installed it using `grails install-plugin remoting` command. Then I have created RemoteService.groovy as follows

```
class RemoteService {
static remote = [
    protocol: 'rmi',
    iface: RemoteInterface,
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '1199',
]
}
```

RemoteInterface.java is defined in src/java folder:

```
public interface RemoteInterface{
   void sayHello(String name);
}
```

I also have the following controller:

```
class MyController {
def remoteService
def index = {
    remoteService.sayHello("Andrey")
}
}
```

And then I launch the application and navigate to http://localhost:8080/MyContoller, I get sayHello - MissingMethodException. I did not find how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare this method in your RemoteService like this:

```
class RemoteService {
static remote = [
    protocol: 'rmi',
    iface: RemoteInterface,
    host: 'localhost',
    port: '1199',
]

void sayHello(String name){}
}
```